# Identify a $|Ψ(0)⟩$ with $A|Ψ(0)⟩≠a|Ψ(0)⟩$ $\forall$ $A$ & $|Ψ(0)⟩=\sum a_j\lvert\chi_j\rangle$ for some $A$ and its eigenstates$\lvert\chi_j\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, eigenvalue, observables

Is it possible to put a quantum system in a state at time $t=0$, which is not the eigenstate of any observable, but at the same time can be linearly expanded using the eigenstates of some observable?

i.e The system is in $\lvert\Psi(0)\rangle$ such that $A\lvert\Psi(0)\rangle\neq a\lvert\Psi(0)\rangle $ for any observable $A$. But  $\lvert\Psi(0)\rangle=\sum a_i\lvert\chi\rangle$ for some observable $A$ and its eigen states $\lvert\chi_j\rangle$.

If a system can be put in such a state , is it true that we can never associate any definite value for ANY of the observables associated with the system at time $t=0$ , when we haven't yet performed any measurement?

If the second statement is also true, it would mean that we cannot have ANY information about the system at time $t=0$ , when no measurement is done?

Of course, the last two question would become pointless if you could provide an example of a physically realizable state satisfying the condition mentioned.

Comment: What is $\left|\Psi\right> = \sum a_i A$ supposed to mean, how is the state supposed to be a sum of operators? Also, if you have a state $\left|\psi\right>$ there will always be the projector $P = \left|\psi\right>\left<\psi\right|$ to that state, which is an observable (since it is a self-adjoint operator) and of which $\left|\psi\right>$ is an eigenstate. So you can never realize a $\psi$ that is not the eigenstate of some observable $P$.

Comment: The last equation specifies the condition that it is possible to expand the state \lvert\Psi(0)\rangle  ,as a linear superposition of the complete set of eigenstates \lvert\chi_j\rangle of some operator A.

Answer (score 0):

This is a given:

> $\lvert\Psi(0)\rangle=\sum a_i\lvert\chi\rangle$ for some observable $A$ and its eigen states $\lvert\chi_j\rangle$.

If $A$ is an observable then its eigenvectors form a basis and any arbitrary state $\lvert\Psi\rangle$ can be expanded as a linear combination of them.

---

On the other hand, the first half of your question,

> Is it possible to put a quantum system in a state which is not the eigenstate of any observable

is *much* fuzzier, because it's ambiguous what you mean by "observable".

- If by that you mean "a hermitian operator", then the answer is no: simply take $A= |\Psi⟩⟨\Psi|$ and you'll get a hermitian operator for which $|\Psi⟩$ is an eigenstate.
- However, that's not necessarily a physical observable that you can realize in the lab. Generally, we often restrict our attention to [algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra) of operators, typically the ones generated by position and momentum, as the observables that can be physically realized. In that case, then yes, it is perfectly plausible that a given state will not be an eigenstate of a realistic algebra of observables.